# How create an Ubuntu 16.04 mirror using rsync

Tags: 16.04, rsync, mirrors

I need create a mirror only of Ubuntu 16.04 and with rsync because is over a CentOS server and can not use apt-mirror or debmirror. If I use `rsync -a --bwlimit=128 rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu /media/mirror/ubuntu` this command go to download all the ubuntu repository, I need only 16.04

Comment: Does this article help? I think you need to set switches to exclude certain files/types to achieve what you want with rsync

Comment: Not the slightest idea how to do it

Comment: Sorry, I think my link didn't work.. http://www.osguides.net/common-software/83-switches-available-in-rsync.html